# Intel ESRT2 RAID array is not recognized by Debian

Tags: debian, raid, intel

We have a new server here with an Intel Server Board S1200BTL and I'm trying to set up a RAID 1 for data storage. I have Debian 6 installed on an SSD, and two 2TB hard drives that are supposed to be in a RAID 1 array.

The onboard SATA controller uses Intel® Embedded Server RAID Technology II, and I configured the two 2TB drives to be in a RAID 1 array. On startup, the messages from the RAID controller indicate that the array is online.

Now, when I look at it under Linux I still see two separate drives `sdb` and `sdc`, while I expected to only see the virtual drive created by the RAID here.

Am I misunderstanding this and I still need some driver support for the RAID here? Or is there anything else besides creating the array I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This controller seems to be a Fake-RAID Controller (not a real hardware raid controller since it's needing a software driver within the OS). You need separate drivers for this. Normally you can download these from the server vendors website.

Comment: Thanks, as Debian is not explicitly supported by the drivers I found I'll go with a pure software RAID.